# How i can access my data in react frontend after i get paginated data from faunadb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, serverless, faunadb

My response from faunadb database to the frontend react looks similar to this but i dont know how to reach to the data object which is containing (letter and extra) keys. I have used map function in my frontend as well but it didn't work.

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("Letters"), "101"),
      "ts": 1565299176485000,
      "data": {
        "letter": "A",
        "extra": "First"
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("Letters"), "102"),
      "ts": 1565299176485000,
      "data": {
        "letter": "B",
        "extra": "second"
      }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response.data[i].data
```

Where i is the index of the array you wish to reach.

Or:

```
response.data.map(o => console.log(o.data))
```

This will log the contents of the data object nested in the array that is nested within the outer data object.